# CKEditor: How to get only characters

Tags: ckeditor

I'm using `wordcount` plugin for `CKEditor`. It perfectly displays wordcount and characters count ignoring spaces.

How do I get only characters(without spaces/line-breaks)? Is there any default API provided `CKeditor` or wordcount plugin?

`editor.getData()` - returns complete text with HTML

`editorContent.text().trim()` - returns text(without HTML) but it doesn't ignore line-breaks and spaces.

Comment: https://ckeditor.com/old//forums/CKEditor-3.x/Character-count

Comment: Dont Think so, you Can write your own plugin inspired by the other.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no official API or plugin for that.

Instead of trimming `editorContent.text()` you could `replace` all whitespace characters using regex (e.g. `/\s/g`).